# Change language on Facebook SDK for Android

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I'm currently using the Facebook SDK for Android to post messages onto your facebook wall from within my mobile application. All Facebook views are now by default displayed in French, but I want them to be in Dutch. I think this is because Facebook detects I'm living in Belgium, and wrongly sets the language to French. The language setting on my Dalvik VM, however, is Dutch.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. My DALVIK VM language setting was set to "Dutch (Belgium)", but setting it to "Dutch (Netherlands)" solved the problem. It's a dirty, but apparently effective solution.

Comment: Hi! Can you tell me exactly what you did? You did not just change the language on device right? Thank you

Comment: Yes, I did! I changed the system language (i.e. the OS language) from 'Dutch (Belgium)' to 'Dutch (Netherlands)', which solved the problem.