# Android Facebook SDK Response Language

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, response

Im developing an Android App which uses the new Facebook 3 SDK. I make requests to the database via FQL to get for example unread Facebook notifications. This works great but only the Language of the response is wrong. 
If i make a request from a german network and smartphone i get an english response.
Why is this so?
I tryed to set a language by opening the session but there is no way.

Thanks and greetings
Julien

Comment: try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10242043/1056359)

Comment: i already tryed to change the system language but it still not works

Comment: it also depends (i think) on the language the user has defined in his profile

Comment: My language in facebook is allready set to german but the response still is in english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can add locale=de_DE as a parameter to your FQL request.